# Why does CTRL not work in VirtualBox VMs?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, keyboard, shortcut-keys, virtualization

I have recently noticed that for some reason when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> in a VM in VirtualBox it doesn't get through... So I can't easily copy and paste etc, it just doesn't get through, the VM doesn't think that I've pressed anything when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or at least it doesn't do anything, why is this? It doesn't seem to matter what I run as guest, and it didn't happen before with these same VMs so it's not that they all just don't like it, the problem probably is with VirtualBox. I have tried running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

**Information Update:**

Neither the left, nor the right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys actually do anything, they don't even seem to interact with Virtual Box because pressing the right one should change something in it.

I have tried installing the Guest Additions CD in my VMs, but it makes no difference to my problem.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
Version: 5.0.14 r105127
```

Comment: VB uses left ctrl for controlling guest, right ctrl for host. That way you can use ctrl left for your guest os, and right for controlling vbox window

Comment: @Serg: Well, neither of them seem to do anything in VB/VM...

Comment: May be a version bug. I'm on 14.04, works alright here:)

Comment: Could it be a gnome thing?. Maybe the CTRL key is assigned by it to some function.

Comment: Already asked on SuperUser: [Ctrl key doesn't work in Virtual Box, Linux host](http://superuser.com/questions/102834/problem-with-ctrl-key-in-virtual-box)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have figured out the problem!

The problem was that for some reason when one has the `Show location of pointer` option enabled in the `gnome-tweak-tool`, as this is assigned to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, for some reason this prevents programs from capturing this key. So disabling that option in the `gnome-tweak-tool` fixes the issue.

Comment: amazing. how did you figure that out?

Comment: @towi: Because it was the only recent change I had made to the settings in terms of the keyboard and mouse in any way. So I put two and two together and gave reverting the setting a choice and thankfully it worked!

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome, Xorg)

Comment: @apos: Yes, I seem to remember hearing about the fix for this bug being released.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the guest additions installed?  This helps with a lot of these issues.

In the VirtualBox window running your VM:

**Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image**

Or, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Follow the prompts and then restart your VM and it should work.

As others have mentioned, <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> is the host key by default and as so will not work for copy/paste type actions but the left one works fine.

Comment: Any keyboard shortcut with "CTRL" in it isn't going to do me that much good... :P

Comment: I was thinking your VM might be stuck using the ctrl key for host tasks and that is why ctrl isn't working within the VM.  Using right ctrl + D executes on the host, not the VM in my understanding (specifically the right one, not left)

Comment: Ok, anyway, I have tried install Guest Additions, but it still doesn't work...